# Enterprise Application Not installing on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have an enterprise application that is deployed via a web service. This application has installed on devices previously, but now it is refusing to install on all but **one** device. Many of my colleagues have downloaded the application without a problem through our web service, all this is, is a simple link on a webpage linking to an IPA file.

Steps already checked and taken:

Provisioning profiles valid.(both development and ad-hoc distribution)

Checked other devices (4s,5s) to make sure it does install properly.

Checked security to and from the device.

Checked connectivity to and from the device. ( Wifi, VPN, Cellular, )

Devices updated to 8.2 + , application target 8.2.

Checked the storage on the device to make sure its not full.

I am aware of installing the application through iTunes, however I have not yet had the opportunity to do so.

**EDIT:** I should mention that this application previously installed successfully on the very same device that I'm having a problem with now, This has only come around since a release made only recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speaking from experience try these steps ...

1. Make sure you are serving the app using URL like `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/App.plist`
2. Make sure that the `App.list` points to the `App.ipa` over `https` connection
3. Make sure that the `https` connection uses **valid SSL certificate** from **trusted Certificate Authority**

If still does not work then ...

1. Connect the device to your Mac
2. Open Xcode
3. Open Window > Devices
4. In Devices window find your device in the left panel and select it
5. On the bottom left of the right panel in the window click the "up arrow in box" icon, this will bring up the Device console
6. Clear the console
7. Try to install the app on the Device and watch the logs for error messages

Comment: As per your suggestion, i have checked that the link is valid and it is, it is also over a https connection.

I have not yet had the opportunity to try your second suggestion, since i do not currently have access to the device, but i will certainly try the second suggestion. Thank you .