# enterprise distribution of iphone app in xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using XCode 6.3.1 and developing app for IOS. Application development and testing done. I want to publish my app to my organisation members who located globally. For this I have an enterprise account and I have generated a distribution certificate and select it in XCode. The Ipa file generated successfully without any plist file. I have modified a .plist file and put it together at one of the secure server at my organisation.

using  windows server:2012 and IIS 8.

I have define following Mime Types: .plist as application/x-plist. and .ipa as application/octet-stream

When I am trying to access .plist file using hyperlink it shows [image]

Comment: Check my recommendations in my answer on same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668511/enterprise-application-not-installing-on-iphone-5s/29670697#29670697

Comment: We have this, when the URL to the ipa file is not HTTPS.

Comment: For extension .plist I use the mime type text/xml